# Is there an easy way for deep cloning a list in Kotlin?

Tags: java, list, kotlin, arraylist, clone

I need to clone an ArrayList of type Any which contains only strings and Arraylists that contain only strings and arrayLists that ... . A shallow copy does not work for me as I need to have every element cloned. My idea is to loop through every element or to convert the ArrayList to a String and than back to an ArrayList ( using the commas and brackets in the string). Any idea how to do this easier?  ( Java answers are appreciated too as I think it is convertable to Kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun cloned(arrayList: ArrayList<Any>): ArrayList<Any> {
  return arrayList.map {
    when (it) {
      is ArrayList<*> -> cloned(it.toList() as ArrayList<Any>)
      else            -> it
    }
  } as ArrayList<Any>
}
```

Comment: Works pretty well too. Your answer is in Kotlin already and uses type ArrayList so I do not even have to cast expressions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple recursive method to deep copy every nested list. Here's a demonstration using Java streams:

```
List<?> deepCopy(List<?> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(e -> e instanceof List ? deepCopy((List<?>)e) : e)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```